# Book Recommendation for spin-orbit coupling

Tags: condensed-matter, angular-momentum, solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, spin-orbit

I am wondering if there were any recommendations for any books that are around graduate level in regards to the discussion of spin-orbit coupling and the Rashba spin-orbit coupling

Comment: The usual way to go is *Spin-orbit Coupling Effects in Two-Dimensional Electron and Hole System* by Roland Winkler, Springer . What kind of research do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

[*Optical orientation*](https://www.elsevier.com/books/optical-orientation/meier/978-0-444-86741-4) is the standard reference - it does not actually contain the discussion of Rashba coupling, but provides necessary general background about the bulk mechanisms of spin-orbit coupling, spin dynamics, optical response, etc.

Rashba became popular in the context of spintronics in early 2000s, so one is likely to find something by looking in this direction.